# Maximum matching blossom algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms, matching

https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S16/projects_reports/shoemaker_vare.pdf

Why do we use blossom contrast in maximum matching?
The examples that I have seen can easily be solved by just iteratively finding a augmenting path and complementing it. I am talking about edmond blossom algorithm.

Edit:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheBlossomAlgorithmForMaximumMatching/

this is what I was looking for in the first step we have only 13 edges and we can not find any augmenting path.

now due to bloosom contrast we have increased matching by 1 edge.

Comment: Apparently the difficulty is *finding* augmenting paths in non-bipartite graphs. Do you have any algorithm in mind?

Comment: This might run into problems if there are odd cycles. See for example Section 3 here: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~zwick/grad-algo-0910/match.pdf.

Comment: The algorithm in Section 3 is only guaranteed to find an augmenting path in bipartite graphs. Perhaps you have a different algorithm in mind.

Comment: It’s all in Section 3. Read it carefully.

Comment: It’s impossible to give an example where the algorithm fails without knowing the algorithm.

Comment: Edmonds’ algorithm works. You are suggesting an improvement, but only hinting at it. It’s impossible to figure out whether the improvement works unless you describe it.

Comment: Edmonds’ algorithm finds a maximum matching in any graph.

Comment: Edmonds’ algorithm does contract blossoms. If you have a different algorithm in mind, you’ll have to spell it out.

Comment: I don't follow. Blossom contracts blossoms.

Comment: This doesn't describe the algorithm completely, since you have to explain how to find an augmenting path.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I got the example.http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheBlossomAlgorithmForMaximumMatching/

Comment: If this is something you could find yourself, I'm not sure why you're disappointed. It is *you* who has to make the effort.